# Phone number for testing Stripe connect standard account onboarding?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm testing onboarding for a a Standard Stripe Connect account, [following the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#using-oauth) and using the phone number `00000000000` but:

[image]

I've tried 9 zeros and 10 zeros but both give the same result. I also tried removing the country prefix, but you have to select *a* country (removing country code is not an option).

Docs do say:

> Force-skip the account form instead of having to fill out an entire account application (Standard)

But what if I want to see what customers see? Is that simply not possible, even in test mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That test phone number is specifically for Express onboarding, with Standard you'd skip the form entirely as you pointed out.

If you want to see what customers see, you could add a real phone number to get through the flow but stop short of actually submitting the form.

Comment: I think for the real phone number it's still hard because the test customer is not from my country, I do not have phone number from that other country. I guess I could guess one, but not the best way to do it. In any case, knowing there *isn't* a way is still useful, as it means I won't keep looking for a way.